# Create a Flowchart Quine

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

A flowchart algorithm is a type of pseudocode designed for human readability and makes it easy to see the program flow.

For this program, you need to output your own program as a flowchart. You may not read your own source code and the output must be a PNG of any size.

The flowchat must be a step by step representation, therefore the number of blocks in your chart should roughly the same number of operations in your program.

Please include your code's output in your answer.

The shortest code wins.

### Specs

These are guidelines, if your language is not good enough to make the necessary calculations easily, you may approximate the shape as good as you can.

#### Conditional

The largest angles in this diamond shape should be `126.86°` and the smallest angles should be `53.18°`. The colour of it should be HTML colour `#E5E4E2`. All of the sides should be the same length.

#### Data Input/Output

The largest angles in this parallelogram should be `116.57°` and the smallest angles should be `63.43°`. The colour of it should be HTML colour `#667C26`. The long side to short side ratio should be 3:2.

#### Process

This should be a rectangle with the colour being HTML colour `#FBF6D9`. The dimensions should be in the height-length ratio 2:3.

#### Terminator

This should be an ovaloid with the colour being HTML colour `#B38481`. The dimensions should be in the height-length ratio 2:3.

#### Arrowhead

This should be an isoceles triangle with the smallest angle being `40°` and the two bigger angles being `70°`. The entire arrow must be of HTML colour `#000000`.

http://www.utexas.edu/courses/streeter/s15-5037.04/Overheads/Symbols.jpg

Comment: I'm really unclear on how flowchart units are expected to correspond to code units. You say 'the number of blocks in your chart should roughly the same number of lines in your program", but a line can contain many operations. Could the whole program sans output go into a basic processing symbol?

Comment: There are no specs on how the ovaloid corners should be shaped. May we use just a rectangle?

Comment: There are no specs concerning the arrow size. May we omit the arrow entirely, saying it is of size 0? Also, what are the requirements concerning edge routing?

Comment: I think the constraints on the graphics are too strict. In most languages at least one thing will add enormous complexity to draw the correct angles which will make it almost impossible to solve the actual challenge. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Someone use tupper's formula somehow

Comment: Why are you guys nitpicking about the graphical specification so much? There is no reason to use anything except one rectangle, which is a quite straightforward shape.